# Is incrementing an Integer inside IAsyncEnumerable thread-safe in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using the latest `IAsyncEnumerable` feature in C# and have the following code:

```
private async Task KeepStreaming()
{
    int someCounter = 0;
    
    await foreach(var item in _someService.ReadAllAsync())
    {
        someCounter++;
        // skipped rest of the logic for brevity
    }
}
```

Do I have to worry about thread-safety when incrementing the counter?

How about if `_someService.ReadAllAsync()` was replaced with `_someChannel.Reader.ReadAllAsync()` assuming the channel was created as following:

```
Channel<Foo> _someChannel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<Foo>(
    new UnboundedChannelOptions {
        AllowSynchronousContinuations = false,
        SingleReader = true,
        SingleWriter = false
    });
```

Comment: Thread safety is a concern when there's concurrency involved, not asynchronicity - so no, you don't have to worry about it

Comment: Not unless you have concurrent async forks like this: `await Task.WhenAll(KeepStreaming(), KeepStreaming())`, which you probably don't.

Comment: @noseratio even with `someCounter` being scoped to each method?

Comment: Oh I overlooked it, thought it's a class member, sorry. Then it's certainly thread-safe. By itself, `await foreach` doesn't have any concurrency inside, more or less it works like this: https://github.com/noseratio/coroutines-talk/blob/36c0f5ea62174b1193a7df018ba1a98e88a66075/Coroutines/AwaitForEach.cs#L17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is safe, and no you don't need to worry about it.

That is entirely thread-safe as long as the code consuming the iterator doesn't break any usage expectations by accessing the iterator concurrently (which would need to be written explicitly - meaning "not `await foreach`" - and would be a fault of the consuming code, not yours).

To be explicit (see comments) - it is relevant here that the variable in discussion is scoped within the iterator block. If it were a field on the instance, then it *could* have thread safety concerns.

Comment: However, if there is another piece of async code that is concerned with `someCounter`, and if the code executes without a synchronization context, there [may be](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html#beware-implicit-parallelism) threading issues.

Comment: @GSerg `someCounter` is scoped inside the iterator block. No other code can access it.

Comment: @MarcGravell so if instead of `_someService` I had `ChannelReader<Foo>.ReadAllAsync()` with multiple writers pushing on `ChannelWriter<Foo>` from multipe threads I would still be `safe` inside the `KeepStreaming` method?

Comment: @camilo the intent of the edit (the addition of the 3rd paragraph) is to specifically limit the applicability to the scenario being discussed

Comment: @MaYaN woah now, that's a lot of cheese to move at once! Safe from what? How was the channel created? Did it expect multiple writers? (That's a configuration option in the construction)

Comment: @MarcGravell updated to reflect my earlier comment.

Comment: @MaYaN will the multiple writer configuration: again, all should be well